# Linker error: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9.1

I'm trying to run my UITests target in Xcode 9.1. The actual app runs, but the UITests target is giving me this error. I've tried restarting, reinstalling pods, updating pods, changing various build settings, deleting and relinking frameworks. Any ideas?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__T010LearnerLog8DurationCMa", referenced from:
>         __T017LearnerLogUITests21testAddPreviousDrivesC0deF5DriveyyF in testAddPreviousDrives.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Let me know if you need any more info!

**Edit**
It happens when I uncomment the second line here. With it commented out it runs fine.

```
let realm = try! Realm() //Connect to realm
//print(realm.objects(Journey.self))
```

Comment: Have you added the pods to your `UITests target`?

Comment: You need to define the test target in your pods file inside your app target and remove "inherit defaults"

Comment: I believe so. Here is my podfile: https://pastebin.com/QV2jbQA7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't do many things in UITests...one of which is Realm.